# String to value

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am producing a report for some mailboximportrequests to show how much data has been uploaded.

The Excel file is asking everything to be displayed in GB.

My script results give me the text string for example....

1.008 GB (1,082,195,968 bytes)

I know about using the "-replace '^([0-9.]+).+','$1'" to just give me the value but that does work if the answer is in MB and not GB

I did this on some testing and one of the imports shows as 533GB instead of 0.533GB

How can I just get the bytes out of the string (1082195968) so I can the convert it to GB

The relevant piece if the script is...

```
$file = get-filename
$inputfile = import-csv $file 
foreach ($f in $inputfile)
{
$PSTImportstats = Get-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox $f.mailbox | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics | where {$_.name -like 'Bison*'} |select name,targetalias,AzureBlobStorageAccountUri,TargetRootFolder,status, statusdetail,StartTimestamp,LastUpdateTimestamp,SyncStage,Suspend,LastSuccessfulSyncTimestamp,PercentComplete,OverallDuration,TotalSuspendedDuration,EstimatedTransferSize,EstimatedTransferItemCount,BadItemsEncountered,BytesTransferred

}
```

The values are then added to an Excel sheet using a foreach loop which works but I get the values as described above
TIA

Comment: Please share the script that outputs `1.008 GB (1,082,195,968 bytes)` - it's likely coming from an exchange data type that can be converted back to a numerical value without manual string parsing

Comment: The script is quite large but the relevant piece is
    $PSTImportstats = Get-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox $f.mailbox | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics | where {$_.name -like 'Bison*'} |select name,targetalias,AzureBlobStorageAccountUri,TargetRootFolder,status, statusdetail,StartTimestamp,LastUpdateTimestamp,SyncStage,Suspend,LastSuccessfulSyncTimestamp,PercentComplete,OverallDuration,TotalSuspendedDuration,EstimatedTransferSize,EstimatedTransferItemCount,BadItemsEncountered,BytesTransferred

Comment: And the field your having problems with is `EstimatedTransferSize`?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 fields the estimatedtransfersize and the bytestransferred. Same issue so once I have 1 working I can apply the same logic tot he other one

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange Data API uses something called a [`ByteQuantifiedSize` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff339273(v=exchg.150)) to represent file sizes.

This data type can easily be converted back to a byte count using its [`ToBytes()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff346234(v=exchg.150)):

```
$mboxReqStats = Get-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox $f.mailbox | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics

$mboxReqStats |Select @{Name='EstimatedTransferSize'; Expression = {$_.EstimatedTransferSize.ToBytes()}}
```